# Add scatter plot points in R

Tags: r

I would like to add my own data into a dataframe, and eventually use that data to generate a scatter plot.

But I am having trouble adding 2D points in R. It seems to me that the data for x-axis and y-axis has to be added separately. However, I have multiple points with the same x-coordinate but different y-coordinates.

I have figured out a way to input my data as shown below. But surely there has to be a more efficient way?

```
i1 <- seq (85,85, length.out=5)
c1 <- c(55, 62, 61, 73, 76)

i2 <- seq (105,105, length.out=6)
c2 <- c(64, 72, 73, 82, 87, 88)
```

[image]

Comment: no easy way to do data input, my suggestion is to just input weekly income and weekly consumption in seperate frames (no  need to repeat 85 five times). Once you have the data entered then it will be easy to either pivot or unpivot the data so that the weeks are joined and match up. From there, easy to plot points so that every y has an x value. So recommend to update your code with dataframes that just has the raw data then we can help you figure out how to tidy it and plot it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most normal is to introduce data by col:

```
# several ways to create obs
df = data.frame(X   = c(85,105,122,143,162,182,203,224,242,262),
                Y_1 = 1:10,
                Y_2 = rep(5,10), 
                Y_3 = c(NA,88,NA,113,125,140,NA,160,189,182))

     X Y_1 Y_2 Y_3
1   85   1   5  NA
2  105   2   5  88
3  122   3   5  NA
4  143   4   5 113
5  162   5   5 125
6  182   6   5 140
7  203   7   5  NA
8  224   8   5 160
9  242   9   5 189
10 262  10   5 182
```

And then we can transform it to longer shape:

```
library(tidyr)
df_longer = df %>% pivot_longer(!X)

# A tibble: 30 × 3
       X name  value
   <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1    85 Y_1       1
 2    85 Y_2       5
 3    85 Y_3      NA
 4   105 Y_1       2
 5   105 Y_2       5
 6   105 Y_3      88
 7   122 Y_1       3
 8   122 Y_2       5
 9   122 Y_3      NA
10   143 Y_1       4
# … with 20 more rows
```

Scatter plot using base plot:

```
plot(df_longer$X, df_longer$value)
```

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(df_longer) + 
       geom_point(aes(x = X, y = value, col = name))
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to put data into long format for plotting. Here, I convert all data to numeric, then I pivot to long format, and we can just drop the rows that have `NA` (i.e., the ones that were blank). I also do not save the column names, but can keep them if important for color coding the points.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = NULL, values_to = "y", values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(85, 105, 122), y1 = c(55, 64, 79), y2 = c(62, 
72, 84), y3 = c("", "88", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```